# Iterating and processing JSON Object in recursive loop causes Stack Exceeded Error

Tags: javascript, json, stack-size

I am trying to build a HTML page using JS. The details of what needs to go into the HTML are sent in a json object from the server. Now the json object is structured in such a way that basically mimics the dom structure and I iterate through the object and fetch individual html element data from it and render the HTML string. The problem occurs when I use a recursive function to run through this object. I trigger a Stack Exceeded Error. I guess this is because of the limit on browser stack size. I would like to understand, what would be the best way I can iterate through this object to create the page without causing the script to fail.

```
pageObj Structure ->

//only a representation of object, the size is much larger.

{ "Default" : { "#text" : [ "\n  ",
          "\n"
        ],
      "MainForm" : { "#text" : [ "\n    ",
              "\n    ",
              "\n  "
            ],
          "shippingInfo" : { "#text" : [ "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n    "
                ],
              "@attributes" : { "title" : "Shipping Information",
                  "type" : "FormBlock"
                },
              "Row" : [ { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "fName" : { "@attributes" : { "placeHolder" : "Enter First Name",
                            "title" : "First Name",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "lName" : { "@attributes" : { "placeHolder" : "Enter Last Name",
                            "title" : "Last Name",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "addr1" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Address 1",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "addr2" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Address 2",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "state" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "State",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } },
                    "zipCode" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Zip Code",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "country" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Country",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } },
                    "phone" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Phone",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n        ",
                        "\n        ",
                        "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "day10" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "10 day Shipping ($3)",
                            "type" : "radio"
                          } },
                    "day5" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "5 Shipping ($10)",
                            "type" : "radio"
                          } },
                    "free" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "Free Shipping ($0)",
                            "type" : "radio"
                          } },
                    "overNight" : { "@attributes" : { "title" : "One day Shipping ($20)",
                            "type" : "radio"
                          } }
                  }
                ]
            },
          "userInfo" : { "#text" : [ "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n      ",
                  "\n    "
                ],
              "@attributes" : { "title" : "User Information",
                  "type" : "FormBlock"
                },
              "Row" : [ { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "TextBox" : { "@attributes" : { "placeHolder" : "Select an username",
                            "title" : "Username",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "TextBox" : { "@attributes" : { "placeHolder" : "Select a password",
                            "title" : "Password",
                            "type" : "password"
                          } }
                  },
                  { "#text" : [ "\n        ",
                        "\n      "
                      ],
                    "TextBox" : { "@attributes" : { "placeHolder" : "Eg: name@gmail.com",
                            "title" : "Email",
                            "type" : "text"
                          } }
                  }
                ]
            }
        }
    } }
```

To iterate this object I use a technique below.

```
function iterateJsonObj(obj) {
    for(key in obj) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) || key=="#text") {
            continue;
        }
        else if(obj[key]["@attributes"]!=null)
        {
            htmlStr += createHTMLStr(obj[key], key);
        }

        iterateJsonObj(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: You really exceed the stack size with that tiny little object?

Comment: It was not that tiny, think an entire page, like entire gmail front end coming in as an object. :)

Comment: the issue could be with createHTMLStr...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a degenerate repro case:

```
iterateJsonObj("Some text");
```

Can you see what's going on? The for loop apparently treats strings similarly to arrays of single-character substrings. "Shipping"[0] is "S" which is itself a string...

To fix this, I'd suggest testing that typeof obj[key] === "object" before iterating over it in this way.

Also, write unit tests. They will make your life easier. :)

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, this does seem like an issue. Let me look into it, will update you. Thanks

Comment: +1 along with acceptance :) Also now I will write unit tests.

Comment: +1 I learnt something today... May I suggest obj===Object(obj) to test for objects? (takes care of the case of null).

Comment: obj===Object(obj) will return true for an array.